# JavaCV error when saving a captured image

Tags: java, netbeans, camera, webcam, javacv

This error comes up when I click my Capture button.

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the
>   specified extension) in cv::imwrite_, file
>   C:\build\2_4_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp,
>   line 275
>       Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   C:\build\2_4_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp:275:
>   error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in
>   function cv::imwrite_
>       ]

This is the code for my Capture Button.

```
if (evt.getSource() == btnCapture) {
    webSource = new VideoCapture(0);
    myThread = new DaemonThread();
    Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            myThread.runnable = true;
            t.start();

        }

myThread.runnable = false;
            webSource.release();



                    JFileChooser jFileChooser1 = new JFileChooser("./images");
                 int returnVal = jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this);

                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                     File  file = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
                     String path = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                      f = new File(file.toURI());
                     Highgui.imwrite(file.getPath(), frame);
                }

                FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
         ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                for(int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
                    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
    } 
 byte[] convict_image = bos.toByteArray();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(cam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(cam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: What is the logic in your code, in the first you newed the VideoCapture and then you immediately released it? And also in the line `Highgui.imwrite(file.getPath(), frame);` where and how did you captured the frame? And so problems...

Comment: //btnPause Action event                                                
       (myThread.runnable = false;
        btnOpen.setEnabled(false);
        btnCapture.setEnabled(true);

        webSource.release();)

Comment: //btnOpen Action event                                                                                               {webSource = new VideoCapture(0);
        myThread = new DaemonThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable = true;
        t.start();
        btnCapture.setEnabled(false); 
        btnOpen.setEnabled(true); }

Comment: webSource.retrieve(frame);
                            Highgui.imencode("image.bmp", frame, mem);
                            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                            Graphics g = jPanelPicture.getGraphics();
                            if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() - 150, 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null)) {

Answer (score 0):

When you write an image using `imwrite` you must specify the extension, just do something like this:

```
Highgui.imwrite(file.getPath()+"\\image.jpg", frame);
```

Here the **.jpg** is the extension.

Comment: this error happens when i run the code. { java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Kurt\Desktop\asd (The system cannot find the file specified) }

Comment: Hi! This error is not belonging to the OpenCV, so you can check the given path OK.